# what is a luminous realm?

Tags: jhana, realms

Where is there more information about the luminous realm?  the standard pali is lacking. what is the relationship with jhana?

from  [MN 115](https://suttacentral.net/mn115/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin):

> “...There are these three elements: the elements of
> the sensual realm, the realm of luminous form, and the formless realm.
> When a mendicant knows and sees these three elements, they’re
> qualified to be called ‘skilled in the elements’.”

Answer (score 1):

It is the realm of the first four (rupa) jhanas. See the [seven planes](https://suttacentral.net/dn33/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin); it is the realm of the rupa jhanas (the first four); see [this discussion](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/what-is-the-realm-of-luminous-form/12453/3) for some sources in DN33. I'm not a Pali expert so not sure why rūpadhātu is translated as "realm of luminous form" here, maybe someone in another answer or comment could elaborate.

Comment: Yes, but I’m not sure I’d exclude he fourth jhana here if for no other reason that it’s still rupa whereas what follows is arupa.  Jhana is secluded from sensual pleasure, so by definition anything 1st jhana and up would be luminous.

Comment: @000 Oh whoops, of course. That's what I get for quickly posting an answer without thinking through my Abhidhamma fully :) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I marked this answer down. It sounds wrong. The Buddha at times dwells in the rupa jhanas & arupa spheres yet i think i cannot be said the Buddha is one of the gods of streaming radiance or one of the gods in Brahma's retinue. In short, the Buddha does not dwell in any "realm" ("loka"). Please take care with the convolutions of Sujato. The translation "these seven planes of consciousness." also sounds wrong but I must think about why.

Comment: Udakarahaka sutta commentary says: "This would correspond to the luminous level of concentration described in the standard simile for the fourth jhana: "He sits, permeating the body with a pure, bright awareness. Just as if a man were sitting covered from head to foot with a white cloth so that there would be no part of his body to which the white cloth did not extend..."

Comment: as i suspected, the translation "planes of consciousness" is wrong & misleading. The meaning of "viññāṇaṭṭhiti" is clearly found in SN 22.54 https://suttacentral.net/sn22.54/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin